# Can windows phone developer with student license add advertising to his app?

Tags: windows-phone, ads

I have a free student windows phone developer license from dreamspark. I am registered at pubCenter and have added AdControl with AdUnitID and ApplicationID from it to my app. Everything works fine, but when I submit my app to the app store advertising is missing.

Is there a problem with the license type or with the submission properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You may not use the DreamSpark software for commercial purposes or commercial software application development, publication or distribution unless you first purchase the appropriate commercial license(s) for the software."

Possibly MS has crippled the advertising functionality until you purchase a commercial developer license.

You might be able to save money on these licenses by signing up for the BizSpark program (http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/about/default.aspx).

You could also be having a fill rate issue (see [How to add Microsoft Advertising on WP7 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350970/how-to-add-microsoft-advertising-on-wp7-app))